# Do you keep your wine/beer making records online?

Tags: record-keeping

I've been looking for a suitable way of keeping my wine records online, whereby I can simply tap in recipe details as I brew, SG during the ferment etc, and it logs these all as individual with the date so I can check back on the information quickly. at a later date.

I tried Evernote but found I might as well be keeping a word processing document for each brew.

Do you keep records online or electronically?

Answer (score 11):

I use [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/demo/edit?id=scABnO9YPL4iWCSndJ20gehID&hl=en&dt=document#document), their spreadsheet has enough functionality to do most calculations you could want. Should you need something more advanced, they allow you to build your own functions using javascript.  The spreadsheets can be mutli-worksheet and you can export [if needed] in many common document formats.

Google also offers their [Standard edition for domains/businesses](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) for free.  Sharing docs works great, even with users outside your [or gmail's] domain.

**Edit:**

There are free, public templates available such as this [Home Brew Log](https://docs.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0Ap_Pif24b_9VdGIxa1d3VDZYeTlPd21CVDNQREgtSVE&mode=public) available on the [Google Docs Template site](https://docs.google.com/templates?type=forms&start=21&sort=rating&view=public&pli=1).

Comment: I also use google docs for this.  Its a good solution.

Comment: +1 for Google Docs spreadsheet. It may not be as fancy as other software, but the simplicity makes it very easy to customise to your preferences and the way you like to work instead of changing the way you work to suit something else.

Comment: +1 I use Google Docs to track details on multiple brew batches, past and present

Comment: My brother and I brew together, so we just have a shared folder with all of our recipes in Google Docs that we can both edit. Very handy tool.

Answer (score 4):

I love [BrewBlogger](http://www.brewblogger.net/). Not only can you store your recipes, but you can make a "brewblog" each time you brew to track tweaks and changes to that batch. It also will calculate ABV, IBU, and SRM for you based on your ingredients. You have to have your own hosting somewhere, but it works great and it's free. The two clubs I'm in have brewblogs [here](http://brewing.trandem.com) and [here](http://minorplanet.org/brew).

Answer (score 2):

I currently use Dropbox to store my recipes.

Comment: In the form of what... Word docs?

Comment: I have an excel sheet I keep using. It has a bunch of formulas built in for mash temp & volume, etc.

Comment: Cool! I use both applications ... Google docs probably has more to offer than dropbox in this regard because you get a browser based editor as well.

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking about tossing 'em up on google docs and see if they convert correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I've started http://www.brew-journal.com/ … online, open-source.  Feel free to join, run your own instance, contribute patches, &c.

Answer (score 1):

I have a copy of [BeerSmith](http://beersmith.com/) installed in a [DropBox](http://dropbox.com/) folder. Works great for keeping my recipes, records, stock etc. synced between by computers.

Answer (score 0):

I've just located Fermsoft's [Online Wine Log](http://www.fermsoft.com/log/index.php) which is great for wine brewers, though not really suitable for beer etc. The data entry is nice, but I'd have liked to have seen some analysis in the reports it produces, more like their offline software, [Amphora](http://www.fermsoft.com/amphora/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use desktop software (BeerAlchemy), but several of my friends swear by [BeerCalc](http://www.haandbryg.dk/cgi-bin/beercalc.cgi), made by a Danish homebrewing site -- it's pretty great for setting up and sharing recipes.