# Resources for Record Keeping?

Tags: record-keeping

I currently keep track of each brew in a little notebook and I have sort of a template I created myself for the brew date, date moved to secondary, bottle date, gravities, ingredients, etc.

Are there any resources available for printing out premade record sheets?  I could hole punch them and put them in a binder.

Comment: Sorry if this looks like the same question as http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/310/do-you-keep-your-wine-beer-making-records-online      I intended this to be about record keeping on paper and didn't think it would overlap with the question about doing it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brewkaiser has a [pretty detailed brew log](http://braukaiser.com/wiki/index.php/Keeping_Log).

Comment: While all of the pdf solutions were similar (thanks divided and Nicholas)  I liked how much information this brew log covers.  Its well organized and the graphing areas are a nice touch.

Answer (score 3):

Basics of Home Brewing has a simple pdf log here:

http://www.basicsofhomebrewing.com/downloadables/HomeBrewLog.pdf

Here is a brewing log software available for free download:

http://www.softforall.com/HomeEducation/FoodBeverage/Home_Brew_Log05030049.htm

Comment: Is the free software a demo version?  The page says that it costs 15 USD.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that this is a free trial.  Yes, it's $15.

Answer (score 1):

Randy Mosher has one [here](http://www.radicalbrewing.com/rbdown.html).